# Apache AliasMatch and DirectoryMatch not working?

Tags: apache-2.2

I have the following config - please notice the Alias and Directory equivalent -- uncommented they work as expected but the dynamic/regex based versions don't - any ideas???

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

  ServerName  temp.dev.local
  ServerAlias temp.dev.local
  DocumentRoot "C:\wamp\www\temp\public"

  <Directory "C:\wamp\www\temp\public">
    AllowOverride all
    Order Allow,Deny
    Allow from all
  </Directory>

  # Alias /private/application/core/page/assets/images/ "C:/wamp/www/temp/private/application/core/page/assets/images/"
  # <Directory "C:/wamp/www/temp/private/application/core/page/assets/images/">

  AliasMatch ^/private/application/(.*)/(.*)/assets/images/ /private/application/$1/$2/assets/images/
  <DirectoryMatch "^/private/application/(.*)/(.*)/assets/images/">
    Options Indexes FollowSymlinks MultiViews Includes
    AllowOverride None
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
  </DirectoryMatch>

</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 1):

The `AliasMatch` there isn't altering the path at all - I'm gonna guess that's not intended?

```
AliasMatch ^/private/application/(.*)/(.*)/assets/images/ /private/application/$1/$2/assets/images/
```

Change to:

```
AliasMatch ^/private/application/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/assets/images/ "C:/wamp/www/temp/private/application/$1/$2/assets/images/"
```

*aside: I swapped the `.*`s to avoid matching `/`, to avoid some unintentional hits to the matches.*

Your `DirectoryMatch` also contains a URL path and not the filesystem path.  It can probably just be:

```
<Directory "C:/wamp/www/temp/private/application/">
```

The config you have in there would work great for a `LocationMatch`, though, if you prefer:

```
<LocationMatch "^/private/application/[^/]*/[^/]*/assets/images/">
```